# simulate a Enter key pressed on mouse click (ubuntu)

Tags: counter-strike, mouse, ubuntu

I am playing cs1.6 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1), but I have this weird problem of mouse click in the game, only with pistols and guns, whenever I fast click to shoot after two/one bullets fired theres a delay (mouse dont even shoot bullets for a second) in shooting.

But when I use Enter key for shooting the bullets get fired smoothly (the whole round).

Now I am looking for some way to simulate Enter key pressed on mouse left click.

Can we do that ?

Comment: Installing a proper mouse driver should solve a lot of issues (and give you the possibility to remap the keys). Logitech G-Hub for example lets you do this.

Comment: @dly I dont think this mouse needs a driver ( Logitech wireless m185 )

Comment: Usually they don't, correct. But the software isn't just a driver nowadays. It also comes with some perks to customize your mouse behavior, such as key mapping, DPI settings, etc. I'm not sure how it works with a cheap mouse like that, though.

Comment: This question is far outside of the scope of Arqade (the fact that the mouse click is being given to a game is tangential), and belongs on [su]

Comment: SU is not a good place to solve Counter-Strike problems. The problem is game specific (mouse lags when shooting too quickly) and should be treated as such, regardless of the possible answers. Rebinding a mouse key to the keyboard is only one of the possible solutions - and one of the worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who want to achieve this on Linux,

I made a c++ program to capture mouse click and have `Enter` key pressed just after.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct input_event event;
    int fd, bytes;
    unsigned char data[3];
    bool down = false;

    const char *pDevice = "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if01-event-mouse";

    fd = open(pDevice, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR Opening %s\n", pDevice);
        return -1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        memset((void *)&event, 0, sizeof(event));
        bytes = read(fd, (void *)&event, sizeof(event));
        if (event.type == 1 && event.code == 272 && event.value == 1)
        {
            down = true;
        }
        if (event.type == 1 && event.code == 272 && event.value == 0)
        {
            down = false;
        }
        if (down)
            system("xdotool key Return");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program I tried to read the mouse events and data directly from the device in "/dev/input/by-id", my device events file name is "usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if01-event-mouse".

Once you have the events in a variable (i.e event), my mouse left button code is 272, not sure it is the universal code number for mouse left button, event.type = 1 ( not sure about this even ), event.value = 1 is mouse button down/pressed event whereas event.value = 0 is mouse up/released event.

Once mouse is pressed we have to hit `Enter` key on keyboard, for that I used `xdotool`, make sure you installed `xdotool`.

`xdotool key Return` triggers the Enter key pressed event on keyboard.

compile it to produce an executable named `mouse`

then you can run it using `sudo ./mouse&`

`&` is to run the command in background.

Thats it, now whenever your mouse left key is pressed, the `Enter` key on your keyboard is pressed until you release the button click.

**Note:** This program uses 100% cpu coz of the infinite while loop, but its normal.

I tested this on cs1.6 when I fired from pistol using mouse left key down, whole round fired automatically coz of `Enter` key pressed till I held the mouse key up.

Make sure you put `Enter` key to Fire in keyboard shotcuts in settings of cs1.6, I have `Enter` key as primary and `-` key as alternate to Fire in keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Just switch to windows, I installed windows10 and found siginificant difference in playing, now my mouse fires pistols intantly as I click, maybe wine makes a software a bit slow in ubuntu, and downloading maps would take hours using wine, now on windows it gets downloaded in seconds.